# Some Android browsers don't cache Apple Touch Icons

Tags: cache, favicon, android

Looking at my server logs, I found quite a few Android clients that don't cache the Apple Touch Icon and reload it on every page view.

I have the following in the `<head>` of my HTML pages:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/touch-icon.jpg" />
```

In my server logs, I see many visitors from Android clients that keep requesting the icon file on every single page view, sometimes even multiple times per page view:

```
[23/Jan/2017:09:23:42 +0100] "GET /page1.html HTTP/1.1" 200 7468 "http://www.google.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:23:42 +0100] "GET /asset1.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 2141 "http://example.com/page1.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:23:46 +0100] "GET /touch-icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13008 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:23:46 +0100] "GET /touch-icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13008 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:23:46 +0100] "GET /asset2.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1518 "http://example.com/page1.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:23:46 +0100] "GET /touch-icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13008 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:24:11 +0100] "GET /page2.html HTTP/1.1" 200 6873 "http://example.com/page1.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:24:14 +0100] "GET /touch-icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13008 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:24:14 +0100] "GET /touch-icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13008 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:24:14 +0100] "GET /touch-icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13008 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:24:41 +0100] "GET /page3.html HTTP/1.1" 200 7469 "http://www.google.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:24:43 +0100] "GET /touch-icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13008 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
[23/Jan/2017:09:24:43 +0100] "GET /touch-icon.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13008 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; MEDION X6001 Build/MEDION-X6001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

My server sends an `Expires` header, so caching should work fine:

```
$ date -u
Fri Jan 27 17:57:15 UTC 2017
$ curl -s -D - example.com/touch-icon.jpg -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2017 17:57:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 12:49:37 GMT
ETag: "316b-530491800ba40"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 12651
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Expires: Fri, 27 Jan 2017 18:12:16 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

These clients cache CSS and other files successfully. I noticed this issue about three years ago. It seems to affect

- all Android versions up to 7.0,
- all kinds of devices,
- multiple network providers,
- different Webkit-based browsers.

*Mobile Firefox is unaffected.* Has anyone else seen this? What's the reason?

Comment: "...multiple times per page view" - If you are seeing multiple requests "per page view" then there would seem to be something more fundamentally wrong than just the browser cache? Even with no cache at all, you shouldn't see multiple requests?!  It would be useful to see the request headers for such a request... is the `If-None-Match` request header present? Just wondering if there might be a conflict/confusion with the `ETag` header?? Even so, that wouldn't explain the multiple requests.

Comment: "My server sends an Expires header, so caching should work fine:" - Just to clarify, the `Cache-Control: max-age` header will take priority over the `Expires` header in compliant browsers (which is all modern browsers). (`max-age:900` is only 15 minutes?)

Comment: @w3dk I updated the example log entries for a client that requests the file multiple times per page view. Cache timeout is 15 minutes intentionally.

Comment: There's no `Referer` set for these requests - is that usual?